# VBA right alignment

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to insert a logo to the right of a print-area in excel. Given that this is done with only TOP and Left references I have tried the following:

```
Private Sub InsertLogo(Name As String)

    Dim MyPic As Shape
Dim MyLeft As Single, MyTop As Single

FilePath = FolderPath + Name + ".png"

If Not Dir(FilePath) <> "" Then

MsgBox ("No logo exists for " & Name & " in Logos. Save the logo as .png file in the logo folder as " & Name & ".")
Exit Sub
End If

MyTop = MySht.[y7].Top
MyLeft = MySht.[y7].Left - MyPic.Width

Set MyPic = MySht.Shapes.AddPicture(FilePath, _
            msoFalse, msoTrue, MyLeft, MyTop, -1, -1)
```

Anyone have any suggestions what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Replace these lines:

```
MyTop = MySht.[y7].Top
MyLeft = MySht.[y7].Left - MyPic.Width  
Set MyPic = MySht.Shapes.AddPicture(FilePath, _
            msoFalse, msoTrue, MyLeft, MyTop, -1, -1)
```

With these:

```
With MySht.[y7]
    Set MyPic = .Worksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(FilePath, _
        msoFalse, msoTrue, .Left, .Top, -1, -1)
End With
With MyPic
    .Left = .Left - .Width
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much @EEM. Seem like I encounter some problems with the size of the various pictures. Tried to insert the following at the end:

 MyPic.Height = 40
    '' adjust if width dominates height
    If MyPic.Width / MyPic.Height > 3 Then MyPic.Height = 25
    If MyPic.Width / MyPic.Height > 4 Then MyPic.Height = 20

But I guess the scaling of the pictures should be done in advance of the insertion?

Comment: It seems that your original question has been answered. Scaling the pictures is a new question.